# Camera activity does not start on the second time

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I have making a tab based app. There are three tabs. One of the tab is used to camera. So when I press camera tab then it opens up camera activity so that I could take pictures. Until here it works fine. When I take picture then that picture is showed in ImageView. **From here when I press any other tab and then I press camera tab then camera activity does not start.** It keep shows me that previous image on ImageView. What I want is whenever user taps on camera tab then it should opens camera activity. **How can I achieve this effect?**

Here is my code. Below os oncreate method which is in camera activity. So when camera tab is pressed it opens this activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);

    userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
    globalUID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("globalUID");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), globalUID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ivUserImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivUserImage);
    bUpload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bUpload);
    openCamera();
}

private void openCamera() {
    i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(i, CameraResult);
}
```

**Update**

I did this but still the same problem

```
boolean flag = true;
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //flag = true;
    if(flag) {
        openCamera();
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

After following Imran's answer my code looks like this now. I am also adding additional code. But this code still does not work.

```
public class Camera extends Activity {
    ImageView ivUserImage;
    Button bUpload;
    Intent i;
    int CameraResult = 0;
    Bitmap bmp;
    public String globalUID;
    UserFunctions userFunctions;
    String photoName;
    InputStream is;
    String largeImagePath;
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    public static boolean flag = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera);

        userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
        globalUID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("globalUID");
        //flag = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("flag");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), globalUID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ivUserImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivUserImage);
        bUpload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bUpload);
        //openCamera();
        if(flag ==true)
            openCamera();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(flag==true)
            openCamera();
    }

    private void openCamera() {
        i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(i, CameraResult);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        flag = false;
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            //set image taken from camera on ImageView
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            ivUserImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            //Create new Cursor to obtain the file Path for the large image
            String[] largeFileProjection = {
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA
            };

            String largeFileSort = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID + " DESC";
            Cursor myCursor = this.managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, largeFileProjection, null, null, largeFileSort);

            try {
                myCursor.moveToFirst();
                //This will actually give you the file path location of the image.
                largeImagePath = myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));

                File f = new File("" + largeImagePath);

                photoName = f.getName();

                bUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        new Upload().execute(largeImagePath, globalUID, photoName);
                    }

                });

            } finally {
                myCursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my tab activity code**

```
public class DashboardActivity extends TabActivity {
    UserFunctions userFunctions;
    public String globalUID;
    DatabaseHandler db;
    boolean flag = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

        db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        // Check login status in database
        userFunctions = new UserFunctions();

        if(userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(getApplicationContext())){
            //globalUID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("globalUID");
            HashMap<String, String> data = db.getUserDetails();
            globalUID = data.get("uid");
            Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
            TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
            TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
            Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

            //Home
            intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
            intent.putExtra("globalUID", globalUID);
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.home_icon)).setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);

            //Camera
            intent = new Intent(this, Camera.class);
            intent.putExtra("globalUID", globalUID);
            //intent.putExtra("flag", flag);
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("camera").setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.camera_icon)).setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);

            //Albums
            intent = new Intent(this, Albums.class);
            intent.putExtra("globalUID", globalUID);
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.albums_icon)).setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);

            //tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
        } else {
            // user is not logged in show login screen
            Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(login);
            // Closing dashboard screen
            finish();
        }
    }   
}
```

**Here is my whole camera activity**

```
public class Camera extends Activity {
    ImageView ivUserImage;
    Button bUpload;
    Intent i;
    int CameraResult = 0;
    Bitmap bmp;
    public String globalUID;
    UserFunctions userFunctions;
    String photoName;
    InputStream is;
    String largeImagePath;
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    public static boolean flag = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera);

        userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
        globalUID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("globalUID");
        //flag = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("flag");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), globalUID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ivUserImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivUserImage);
        bUpload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bUpload);
        //openCamera();
        //if(flag ==true)
            openCamera();
    }
    /*
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(flag==true)
            openCamera();
    }*/

    private void openCamera() {
        i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(i, CameraResult);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        flag = false;
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            //set image taken from camera on ImageView
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            ivUserImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            //Create new Cursor to obtain the file Path for the large image
             String[] largeFileProjection = {
                     MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                     MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA
             };

             String largeFileSort = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID + " DESC";
             Cursor myCursor = this.managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, largeFileProjection, null, null, largeFileSort);

             try {
                 myCursor.moveToFirst();
                 //This will actually give you the file path location of the image.
                 largeImagePath = myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));

                 File f = new File("" + largeImagePath);

                 photoName = f.getName();

                 bUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   
                     public void onClick(View v) {
                         new Upload().execute(largeImagePath, globalUID, photoName);
                     }

                 });

             } finally {
                 myCursor.close();
             }
        }
    }

    public class Upload extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Camera.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String success = "false";
            Bitmap bitmapOrg = setImageToImageView(largeImagePath);//BitmapFactory.decodeFile(largeImagePath);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

            byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
            String ba1=Base64.encodeToString(ba, 0);

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",ba1));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imageName", photoName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", globalUID));

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.info/android/fileupload.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if(response != null) {
                    success = "true";
                }
                is = entity.getContent();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
            return success;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...progress) {

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String f) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    public Bitmap setImageToImageView(String filePath) { 
        // Decode image size 
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true; 
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o); 

        // The new size we want to scale to 
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024; 

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2. 
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight; 
        int scale = 1; 
        while (true) { 
            if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE) 
            break; 
            width_tmp /= 2; 
            height_tmp /= 2; 
            scale *= 2;
        } 

        // Decode with inSampleSize 
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
        o2.inSampleSize = scale; 
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2); 
        return bitmap;

    }

    public boolean fileData(String guid, String photoName) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), photoName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        JSONObject json = userFunctions.uploadFileData(guid, photoName);

        try {
            if(Integer.parseInt(json.getString("success")) != 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json.getInt("error_msg"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //register_error.setText(json.getString("error_msg"));
                return false;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you are switching between tabs your activity doesnt call onCreate again.

Try moving call to openCamera(); into onResume method and it should be fine.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);

    userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
    globalUID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("globalUID");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), globalUID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ivUserImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivUserImage);
    bUpload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bUpload);

}



protectd void onResume(){
      super.onResume();
      openCamera();
}

private void openCamera() {
    i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(i, CameraResult);
}
```

Comment: I put openCamera in onResume method but now I cannot even see that which is taken on ImageView. In fact, when I tap on save button on on camera activity it take me back to camera activity this keeps continue after taking five or six pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Each `Activity` in an `TabHost` calls `onCreate()` only once for reason of efficiency. This is why the `openCamera()` doesn't get called again and again.

In order to handle this, you can in the parent `Activity` to implement and register an `OnTabChangeListener`, where you can catch which tab is clicked and perform any desired action.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

add `onResume()` in your activity and call openCamera(); from onResume() also as:

```
public static boolean flag = true;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);

    userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
    globalUID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("globalUID");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), globalUID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ivUserImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivUserImage);
    bUpload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bUpload);
if(flag ==true)
    openCamera();
}


       @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
if(flag==true)
            openCamera();
        }
```

and in on `onActivityResut()`

```
flag =false;
```

or on tabclick

```
YourflagActivity.flag=true;
```

Comment: I put openCamera in onResume method but now I cannot even see that which is taken on ImageView. In fact, when I tap on save button on on camera activity it take me back to camera activity this keeps continue after taking five or six pictures.

Comment: @al0neevenings :use one Boolean for putting condition in onResume then if Activity is resumed by  Camara application then no need to call  method openCamera or if activity is resumed by on clicking tab then call openCamera.i think u understand what i want to say

Comment: How would I know whether activity is currently resumed or not?

Comment: make flag = false; in onActvityResult and flag = true on tab click;

Comment: @al0neevenings : just make boolean flag ; global or satic then u can access it wny where in your activity

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12945/discussion-between-imran-khan-and-al0ne-evenings)

Comment: I checked it and modified my code accordingly but same problem

Comment: @al0neevenings : where is your tabtactivity code plz share it

Comment: @al0neevenings : u have try by setting android:launchMode="singleTop" for activity Camera activity in manifast

Comment: and Intent intent= new Intent(context, Camera.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

Comment: sorry @al0neevenings i have forgot these option

Comment: here is my manifest `<activity
            android:name=".Camera"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SONGS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`

Comment: add android:launchMode="singleTop" for Camera in manifast and start it as Intent intent= new Intent(context, Camera.class); intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); and also comment onResume code

Comment: Here is what I did but still same problem. `//Camera
            intent = new Intent(this, Camera.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            intent.putExtra("globalUID", globalUID);
            intent.putExtra("flag", flag);
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("camera").setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.camera_icon)).setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);`

Comment: You mean both tab activity and Camera activity?

Comment: I added whole camera activity. Please see above. I already shared my tab activity.